# Laravel return data correct to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have made a form in blade and im sending the result to my controller. here i run an sql statement. the result of the sql i want to return to the blade but im not getting the data im expecting back.

in my controller i return: `return view('result')->with('data', $result);`. the $result variable is a collection andcontains the following (see photo)

[image: $result variable]

in my blade i have this code for showing the result:

```
@if(isset($data))
 <p>{{$data}}</p>

@foreach($data as $result){
 <ul>
  {{$result->price}} {{$result->item}}
 </ul>
}
@endforeach
```

the result shows like this (see photo)
[image: result]

how could i get the result to show like the following (see photo). so the brackets are not showed in the ul and so i only get a specific item in the p element.

[image: result i want]

i have tried to get the data with:

- $data[0]->quantity
- $data[0]['quantity']

Comment: You are using blade template engine (by default in laravel) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pulling the wrong field.

```
$animal= $request->animal;
```

According to your HTML input this should be:

```
$animal= $request->species;
```

You are also using `->get()` on the DB, which will return a collection.

> The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection instance
> containing the results of the query where each result is an instance
> of the PHP stdClass object

If you want to grab a single row, use `->first()`

You can read more on the docs about grabbing a single row

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $animal= $request->species;
    $resultAnimal= $this->retrieve($animal);
    
    return view('welcome')->with('data', $resultAnimal);
}

public function retrieve($animal)
{
    return DB::table('animals')
    ->where('species', $animal)
    ->first();
}
```

Comment: Hi, i do want to grab all columns but for my p element i would like to grab the first item for display purpose

Comment: To get the first item in the collection, use: $data->first()->animal

Comment: It's because `get` returns a collection, you can still use `->first()` in your blade, `$data->first()` and it will return the first item in the collection. 

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#available-methods

Comment: hi, i have edited my question to make it more clear what i want